# IIS pool access to linked folder

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, web-applications, iis-7

I’ve a web application in ASP.NET in a pool application on my server, in the same server I’ve a web service in another application pool that’s use a domain user to connect a linked folder, my problem is, my web application need to map  another folder on the same disk of the service’s linked folder but when I try to do that was returned an error, it says I can’t map the folder because there an active connection yet.
How can I do that?

Comment: where/when are you getting this error? What exactly does it say?

Comment: I get the error when my web application run a command for map a specific area of the remote disk; the error says “sistema error 0 impossible to map this memory area”, I’ve seen that error appears when I try to map a disk was mapped yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's other way around. Don't map the folder at all.
Let your applications access the files directly through SMB (`\\server\share\file`). If accounts running them are able to *map* those shares, they will also be able to *access* the files.

Comment: I need to map the folder because was protected by password, I can’t access directly, I need run a command for map specific folder by username and password